# JSP and CSS file not loading in browser Java WebApp

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc, jsp

I have the following folder structure for my Maven WebApp Project

```
src
 +-----main
        +-----java
        |       +-----com
        |               +------controller
        |                          +-----HomeController.java
        |
        +-----resources
        +-----webapp
                 +-----resources
                 |          +-----css
                 |                 +-----home.css
                 +-----WEB-INF
                         +-----jsp
                         |      +------home.jsp
                         +-----eLibrary-servlet.xml
                         +-----web.xml
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>eLibrary</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>eLibrary</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<display-name>eLibrary</display-name>
```

eLibrary-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEF-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

HomeController.java:

```
@Controller
    public class HomeController {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String getHomePage() {
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

And in my home.jsp, I'm trying to access the CSS file using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/home.css`

But neither my JSP file(i.e. home.jsp) nor the CSS file(i.e. home.css) is loading in browser and I'm getting HTTP Status 404 when accssing http://localhost:8080/eLibrary/ with a message

> /eLibrary/WEF-INF/jsp/home.jsp

and description

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: Are you using spring boot ?

Comment: Spring Boot-No. I got the error. There's a typo in my eLibrary-servlet.jsp

Comment: *I got the error. There's a typo in my eLibrary-servlet.jsp*  - In that case close this question

Answer (score 1):

You have a type, in here `/WEF-INF/jsp/`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEF-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

change it to `/WEB-INF/jsp/`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in Configuring the Spring DispatcherServlet. You need to mention your **eLibrary-servlet.xml** in **web.xml**. Need to rearrange the web.xml as mentioned in the below link.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-flex/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch02s02.html

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/eLibrary-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Hope this is usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error in your elibrary-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```